# Unable to read korn shell Parameter

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Gone through few Posts in SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087249/korn-shell-passing-arguments-is-not-working-correctly) but unable to resolve the issue. I am passing 4 arguments to a korn shell script. But it doesnt read the 4th arg. Here is the code

```
#Get Input parameters

while getopts ":s:e:n:d" OPT
do
   case $OPT in
      (s) from=$OPTARG;;
      (e) to=$OPTARG;;
      (n) process=$OPTARG;;
      (d) path=$OPTARG;;
      (\?) printerror;;
   esac
done
print "from $from" 1>&2;
print "to $to" 1>&2;
print "process $process" 1>&2;
print "path $path" 1>&2;
```

Then i execute the script like this

```
loaddat.ksh -s 1234 -e 1234 -n 1 -d /d/asa/
```

whatever i do path value does not get printed. Tried with and without quotes. even just as a string like xyz as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the option string, You need a colon after d

```
":s:e:n:d:"
```

because in the command line, option '-d' is expected to be followed by its value, which in this case is a path.

If the option letter in the string 'd' is not followed by ':', getopts won't check for its value.

Comment: Yes it worked. !! btw what s the use of the first ":" before "s" param then?

Comment: That controls how errors are handled by getopts while parsing options.  If the option string starts with a colon, silent error reporting is used. Otherwise, diagnostic messages are printed when there are invalid options or missing option arguments